# Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "function"

Tags: r, rvest, xml2

I am attempting to move files from a source directory if the url tagged matches a list I will generate.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(xml2)

setwd("E:/URLtoTest")

#subset of HTML URLs to move
UrlsToMove <- data.frame(filename = c("https://www.example.com/advisory_group.html"))

#get list of html files
htmlfiles <- list.files(pattern= ".html")

#Return Page
page <- sapply(htmlfiles, function(file){
  tryCatch(
    {link <-read_html(file) %>%
      html_node(xpath = ".//link[contains(@rel, 'canonical')]") %>% 
      html_attr("href")
    if(link %in% UrlsToMove) {
      file.copy(from = paste0("E:/URLtoDateTest", htmlfiles),
                to = paste0("E:/URLtoNewFolderTest", htmlfiles))
    }
    }, error = function(e){print('unknown')})
})
```

I know it's connected to the right directory because the htmlfiles object is showing me the correct number of htmls found in my source directory. But it errors and is retuning "unknown" and not looping.

I tried running just:

```
link <-read_html(file) %>%
      html_node(xpath = ".//link[contains(@rel, 'canonical')]") %>% 
      html_attr("href")
link
```

But I am returning this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : 
  no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "function"
```

I have now edited the function to:

```
#Return Page
page <- sapply(htmlfiles, function(filename){
  tryCatch(
    {link <-read_html(filename) %>%
      html_node(xpath = ".//link[contains(@rel, 'canonical')]") %>% 
      html_attr("href")
    if(link %in% UrlsToMove) {
      file.copy(from = paste0("E:/URLtoDateTest", htmlfiles),
                to = paste0("E:/URLtoNewFolderTest", htmlfiles))
    }
   
    }, error = function(e){print('unknown')})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`file` is a function in R. Change the function argument name to `filename` or `x` or whatever and this should work.

Comment: Thank you! That did help with retrieving the href text, however, it's still not moving my files. I've updated to the above.

Comment: Change `if(link %in% UrlsToMove)` to `if(link %in% UrlsToMove$filename)`